# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements - oh! my, again

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, certificate

I bounced again in this error when trying to install an app neither on my iPhone and iPad. I applied all the suggested measures to no avail. In particular I removed all the profiles for the app from my iPhone, cleaned the derived folder, restarted the iPhone and Xcode, checked the identity between the profile in the project and in the target (I set automatic in the former), tried removing the Entitlement reference and keeping it and even created a new certificate and provisioning profile; all of this for nothing.
Other targets for this project install fine, it works fine on the simulator and submitting it to the app store for TestFlight testing does not create any problem either; so the problem seems just connected to physical debug devices. What else could it be?
Sometimes an "unknown error" pops up instead of the invalid signing one after a very long time since ending compilation.

Comment: I think I found the problem, perhaps due to a problem on the Apple web site, if I had not previously ignored it. When I go to the provision profile section in the Apple web site and edit the iOS development profile, the App id I may select all have the code for distribution, whereas when I click on the project settings the debug profile and identity seem correctly linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found. The issue was due to the Release choice creeped in the scheme build configuration.